# Use of node js to search contents on an in-memory file on 100000 PCs

Tags: node.js, concurrency, scalability, real-time-updates

There is a network of around 100000 PCs, each of which contains an in-memory XML file whose contents I need to search from a central server. This XML file is generated by a windows service that runs on each PC.

The search query is generated at the central server, propagated to each of the PCs on the network, and if information in the in-memory XML matches the search query, then the list of all matching PCs needs to be sent back to the server and results displayed in 20 seconds or less.

In view of the scalability and concurrency requirements, I am planning to utilize node js to solve this problem. But I've never used node js before. Could someone on this forum please guide me how to architect a solution to this using node js? The 100000 PCs are spread across more than 50 LANs. I've been reading up a lot about socket.io and other stuff about node js, but can't figure out a solution to this. Could someone please guide me? Which node package can help me to read an in-memory XML file? If something changes on a PC's in-memory file while a user is viewing results about it on the server, those changes as well need to be updated in real time on the result viewer. Apart from node js, is there anything else using which I could get this done?

Comment: I just struck upon an idea, please let me know how it sounds:

1. I will have a MongoDB (or any other database) instance at the server
2. All the 100000 PCs will be concurrently connected to it, and store the contents of the in-memory XML file in the DB
3. In case of any local updates to the file, the database entry for that PC is immediately updated
4. When a user wishes to search, the DB instance on the server is searched and results returned immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Use Express for NodeJs. It's a webserver, so you can issue HTTP commands to it https://expressjs.com/

Comment: Make sure you accept as an answer if this is the approach you decide to go for (it's the one I'd go for)

Comment: +Peter Morris I'm still deciding what to go for. What is your opinion of all the 100000 PCs being concurrently connected to the Node js server and updating a MongoDB instance with the contents of the in-memory file in real time, and then users querying the MongoDB instance?

Comment: I would avoid XML completely if possible. If not then I'd only use it for a transport format (receive API via some external source) and then update a database. If the data format lends itself well to a document format rather than relational rows then MongoDB would be a good choice

Comment: +Peter Morris Thanks for your comment again. XML is the format of the data at the source, and indeed, it is not in relational format. I'm taking it as it is at the source and pushing it to the MongoDB the same way

Comment: Have the clients push it to a farm of servers which parse the XML and update the MongoDB.